# Convert NSURL to AppleScript file path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, nsurl

I am using NSAppleScript to run applescript from within my application. My problem is that I have an NSURL that I want converted to string. When I convert it, I get: path/to/my/file, but applescript requires path:to:my:file. How can I convert my NSURL into this format? THanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
file "foo:bar:baz"
```

use

```
POSIX file "foo/bar/baz"
```

Answer (score 4):

You might find this useful it will convert the pathString to a HFS style path (with colons):

```
NSString* pathString = [@"~/Desktop/Home.m4v" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSURL* theFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString];

NSString* path = [(NSString*)CFURLCopyFileSystemPath((CFURLRef)theFileURL, kCFURLHFSPathStyle) autorelease];

NSLog(@"path= %@",path);
```